# django: renamed app, but I want to allow old URLs too. How to allow alternate URL patterns to one url namespace?

Tags: django

I have renamed an app in django 2.x, and this is completed successfully. 
However, I want to allow the old URLs to still be used. I could configure the front-end webserver to redirect, but I would like to know best practice for doing this in django.

The old app has gone, so the old URLs now belong to the URL namespace of the new app. 
In my project-level urls.py, I could do this
Attempt 1:

```
  url(r'^NEWAPP/', include('NEWAPP.urls')),
   url(r'^vOLDAPP/', include('NEWAPP.urls')),
```

but this has the disadvantage of including NEWAPP.urls twice, which causes the warning that URL namespace NEWAPP is not unique.

Attempt 2:

```
 url(r'^cin7_sync/|^voga/', include('cin7_sync.urls')),
```

which doesn't work, the | is not working as an 'or'.

Comment: what about adding two different root URLs `include()` two separate files that contain respectively the new and the old URLs?

Comment: IMO a web server redirect is by far the most efficient option - unless there is a reason that you can't do that, do that!